# Android inverse clip

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, clip

I need to specify a rectangle in which the Android canvas CANNOT draw inside of. I know that `clipRect` will specify and area in which to draw in, but I was if I could reverse this effect. In other words how do I draw an object making it draw to the outside of a rectangle. Image for clarification:

[image: Clipping example]

Comment: You can always draw the object and then draw a white rectangle above it

Comment: I am trying to reduce overdraw so this would do the exact opposite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is actually going to be more performant than doing an overdraw.  But you could set a clipping path to the full view, then set a second one to the exclusion zone with Region.Op DIFFERENCE set.  That would set the clipping rect to the difference between the two.

Comment: I'll do some comparisons

Answer (score 12):

With Android O, `Canvas` exposes the API `clipOutPath(Path path)`; for targeting earlier versions, you can use `clipPath(Path path, Region.Op op)` as alluded to by @Gabe Sechan.

The implementation would look something like:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        canvas.clipOutPath(path);
    } else {
        canvas.clipPath(path, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    }
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
```